# mv: cannot stat './temp': No such file or directory on github actions

Tags: ubuntu, github, github-actions

I made a github workflow that takes a folder's contents and stores it temporarily in another directory, it being this:

```yaml
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      
      - name: Create temp folder
        run: |
         cd ..
         cp ./FlexLauncher ./temp -r
         cd ./temp
         ls
         cd ..
      - name: Move temp to main folder
        run: |
         mv ./temp ./FlexLauncher
         ls
```

The results of the first ls show that the folder exists, as I can cd into it and ls the contents.

```
Run cd ..
  cd ..
  cp ./FlexLauncher ./temp -r
  cd ./temp
  ls
  cd ..
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
README.md
main.js
main.py
package-lock.json
package.json
web
```

I get the error in the second step:

```
Run mv ./temp ./FlexLauncher
  mv ./temp ./FlexLauncher
  ls
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
mv: cannot stat './temp': No such file or directory
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Comment: What's your current directory starting in `Move temp to main folder`?

Comment: @Cyrus It is the FlexLauncher directory, I cd to the parent directory first thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsrun) for GitHub actions:

> Each `run` keyword represents a new process and shell in the runner environment. When you provide multi-line commands, each line runs in the same shell.

You can use the "working-directory" attribute to specify the folder where the script should be executed:

```yaml
      - name: Create temp folder
        working-directory: /your/path
        run: |
         cp ./FlexLauncher ./temp -r
         cd ./temp
         ls
      - name: Move temp to main folder
        working-directory: /your/path
        run: |
         mv ./temp ./FlexLauncher
         ls
```

Comment: @123wa Yes, you can do that, but remember that in the next run block you have to go into the folder again.